# Python Pandas - Randomly select rows from a dataframe between 2 two rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called stockPricesDf which has returns data for a number of stocks and is indexed by date:

```
            BBG.XLON.POLY.S  BBG.XLIS.RENE.S  BBG.XLON.ETO.S  BBG.XOSL.STB.S  
date                                                                           
2015-02-24         0.029041         0.005917        0.000601        0.031207   
2015-02-27         0.015975        -0.001821        0.003480        0.004410   
2015-02-25        -0.027660         0.003666       -0.012115        0.008723   
2015-02-24         0.029041         0.005917        0.000601        0.031207
```

Is it possible to select the rows for all stocks between 2 rows.  If for example I asked for all the data between rows 2 and 3 (not selecting rows based on date) I would be returned:

```
    BBG.XLON.POLY.S  BBG.XLIS.RENE.S  BBG.XLON.ETO.S  BBG.XOSL.STB.S  
date                                                                                                     
2015-02-27         0.015975        -0.001821        0.003480        0.004410   
2015-02-25        -0.027660         0.003666       -0.012115        0.008723
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) to slice your desired range using integer indexing, note that the end value is not included and that indexing is 0 based:

```
In [169]:
df.iloc[1:3]

Out[169]:
            BBG.XLON.POLY.S  BBG.XLIS.RENE.S  BBG.XLON.ETO.S  BBG.XOSL.STB.S
date                                                                        
2015-02-27         0.015975        -0.001821        0.003480        0.004410
2015-02-25        -0.027660         0.003666       -0.012115        0.008723
```

Regarding the random selection question you can use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selecting-random-samples):

```
In [170]:
df.sample(2)

Out[170]:
            BBG.XLON.POLY.S  BBG.XLIS.RENE.S  BBG.XLON.ETO.S  BBG.XOSL.STB.S
date                                                                        
2015-02-24         0.029041         0.005917        0.000601        0.031207
2015-02-27         0.015975        -0.001821        0.003480        0.004410
```